# How to upgrade Kubernetes nodes' version without changing the nodes' IPs

Tags: kubernetes

I'm planning to upgrade my kubernetes cluster. My kubernetes cluster is using private cloud platform's VMs as nodes. I have trouble with upgrading nodes because the users of my cluster do not want the (public) IP of their node to change. I want to know how to upgrade kubernetes nodes without changing their IPs.

I referred to AWS EKS self-managed nodes update. They have two options:

1. Migrating to a new node group (make new node group -> cordon & drain -> delete old nodes)

   - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/migrate-stack.html
2. Updating an existing self-managed node group

   - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/update-stack.html

The first option is easy to use and feasible. But since the nodes change, so the IP of the nodes change. This is not the case I want.
The second option uses AWS native "CloudFormation", which I cannot use of.

Is there any way to upgrade nodes without change of the IPs of the nodes?